# How to put/post a video mp4 file on an EDS URI in C#

Tags: c#, automation, video-processing

I want to automate an Attachment application which is set up of 2 requests :

1. Auth requests, it will provide me a valid EDS URI.
2. Put any type of file on EDS URI from 1st request.

Here, in the second request, I want to upload a video (MP4) file. The file is already part of the project.
 I tried in a way like :

```
string filePath = "~\\SampleVehicalVideo.mp4";

byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(attachmentURI, new ByteArrayContent(array .ToArray()));
```

But this is not working. Please help!!!

Comment: Why you use the tilde syntax with a backslash? What’s your environment?

Comment: Please ignore the tilde with backslashes. I get path here by GetDirectory(). Getting the path is not the concern here.

Comment: Can you show details about the error? Without it, and with this little piece of code shown, it’s hard to ged rid of what happensz

Comment: Also array.ToArray() is pure redundancy

Answer (score 0):

I would like to update that, I am able to upload an mp4 file over an EDS URI with following code

```
byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(attachmentURI, new ByteArrayContent(array .ToArray()));
```